# Why is ubuntu-touch tag still in "my tags"?

Tags: support, tags

Once upon a time, I was following [ubuntu-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch) for some reasons, later on I decided not to follow it. Great, I stopped following it and now questions tagged ubuntu-touch are not highlighted. Good. But then, why they still appear in the Unanswered -> My Tags?

[image]

Comment: When did you stop following it? Some stuff takes time to update

Comment: @Seth eons ago...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tooltip for [Unanswered → My Tags](https://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags) read as:

> questions with tags that I've participated

So, it doesn't matter if you follow a particular tag or not, if you have previously participated in a tag, there is a good probability for it to show up in that list.

Questions get highlighted if it has one of the tags which you are following. Since, you have removed [ubuntu-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch) from your favorites, it isn't highlighted anymore. But you have [previously participated in 1 question and 6 answers which have ubuntu-touch as one of the tags](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=user:169736%20%5Bubuntu-touch%5D), which is the reason it shows up in your "My Tags" list.

Comment: I figured out after a while but was too lazy to write an answer D: